# Constant error when attempting to debug c# application

Tags: c#

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I keep getting the error when I try to run/debug my c# forms application. I looked through my project and saw that the only files that said System.Runtime were these 2 files;

```
Random\RandomApplication\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs

Random\RandomApplication\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs
```

They both contain the same content (of course) and say:

```
// <autogenerated />
using System;
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(".NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1", FrameworkDisplayName = "")]
```

I have been looking around but have been unable to find an answer to this.

I am quite new to c#, am I don't really get what it is saying.

I do know that my current .net version is 5.0, and my random stupid guess was that maybe System.Runtime doesn't exist in 5.0, or maybe I need to replace the 3.1 with 5.0, but that is also odd, because this file was autogenerated when I created the new project.

Edit: The problem was pretty much I was using visual studio wrong, I figured out the wrong way I was using it and it is now better. Thanks!

Essentially, I had just come from VSCode to Visual Studio, because VSCode does not support windows forms applications. But what I did not know was that to open things here, you just open the .sln file. I was just opening the overall folder, but when I tried opening the .sln file instead, and using visual studio with that, it worked perfectly. Rookie mistake.

Comment: What are you compiler options (x64,x32, x86)?  When you compile each module is put into the obj folder and then when the executable is created in the project bin folder.  So the code is looking for the obj files and not finding these intermediate files.  The errors must be  shown in the Error list.  If you do not see the error list then use menu View : Error List.

Comment: I believe its x64

Comment: Can you see the exception being throw in Visual Studio (maybe enable the setting "Break on All CLR Exception" in the Exception Settings). Usually System.Reflection errors have an inner exception called "LoaderExceptions" that has more details.

Answer (score 0):

Check `<PropertyGroup>` Node in .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
   <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
   <UseNETCoreGenerator>true</UseNETCoreGenerator>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I now get the error 
/mycomputernamestuff/random/randomapplication/bin/debug/netcoreapp2.0/randomapplication.dll
The system can not find the file specified.

Comment: Do you have core 2.0 installed? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.0